# Переформатирование списка на основе совпадения в первом столбце

Tags: bash, perl, sed, awk

Есть некоторый список, скажем:

```
Friday Jan
Friday Oct
Monday Feb
Monday Mar
Monday Nov
Saturday May
Sunday Aug
Thursday Apr
Thursday Jul
Tuesday Jun
Wednesday Dec
Wednesday Sep
```

Как с помощью `awk`/`sed`/`perl` мне получить список вида:

```
Jan, Oct - Friday
Feb, Mar, Nov - Monday
Apr, Jul - Thursday
Seo, Dec - Wednesday
```

То есть основываясь на названии дня недели, создать новый список "месяцы-деннь недели"?

Comment: в perl: с помощью хешей, где: ключ - день недели, а массив со значением - месяцы, $VAR1 = { 'Friday' => [ 'Jan', 'Oct'] };

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что так долго никто не отвечает.  Элементарный же скрипт на
*AWK*:

```awk
{
    a[$1][length(a[$1])] = $2;
}

END {
    for (w in a) {
        l = "";
        for (m in a[w]) {
            l = l a[w][m] ", ";
        };

        l = substr(l, 0, length(l) - 2);
        print(l " - " w);
    };
}
```

Результат:

```
Jun - Tuesday
Jan, Oct - Friday
Aug - Sunday
Apr, Jul - Thursday
May - Saturday
Feb, Mar, Nov - Monday
Dec, Sep - Wednesday
```